# Automatic backup internet connection, is it possible?

Tags: network, internet

I am trying by best to understand this topic. Apologies if this isn't the correct format or if it's lacking required information, I am little more than a home user. If someone could help point me in the right direction that would be great!

I need to create a fallback internet connection, right now I have two active connections: One ethernet line from a router connected to the landline & one ethernet line from a Netgear M1 (SIM Card) router.

Currently if one network goes down, I manually unplug the ethernet cable from my ethernet switch and replace it with the backup ethernet line. This works great.

Is there any way to automate this process? Is there a piece of equipment that can detect if a line doesn't have a successful connection (a couple of timeouts or something) and switch to the backup line until that fails? I understand there may be ways to do this with ADSL, I am asking specifically if this can be done over ethernet out of two separate routers.

Thank you.

Comment: That won't work on the Ethernet level alone - Internet connections are *routed*, so you need to create a failover scheme on a router. Note that home networking is off-topic here, as are consumer-grade devices and host configurations.

Comment: Detecting loss of connectivity and switching over to a backup connection is certainly possible with (most) business-grade routers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In consumer-level routers, the feature you're looking for is called **Dual WAN**.  ASUS is one vendor whose gamer/prosumer models support Dual WAN.

I don't know if you'll be able to integrate it with the Netgear M1.  A USB LTE adapter for the backup connectivity is more common.

Are you doing this with consumer-level equipment or like a branch office router?  If consumer-level, I bet you will get better responses on the SuperUser section of Stack Exchange.

This section is more focused on professional-level equipment where the means of providing redundancy would be via routing protocols (not available with consumer ISP service) or features such as Cisco *IP SLA* or JunOS [RPM](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/security-rpm-overview.html) and *event scripts* (can work without ISP support.)